# How to simplify a git-status command with a diff-filter, with e.g. git-diff-index

Tags: git

Is there a way to write the following command without grep and without sed?

I think this could be achievable with e.g. `git-diff-index` but I'm overwhelmed by the details.

The original command is:

```
git status -s --porcelain /some/path | grep -E '^(.M|[MA].|\?\?)' | sed -e 's/^.. //g';
```

Is it equivalent to this?

```
git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=AM HEAD -- /some/path
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's start with the `git status` command out of this:

> ```
> git status -s --porcelain /some/path | grep -E '^(.M|[MA].|\?\?)' | sed -e 's/^.. //g'
> ```

The `--porcelain` (or `--porcelain=v1`) output format is an un-color-encoded variant of the `--short` format, which prints two characters for each file name, then a space, then the file name (possibly quoted depending on `core.quotePath` and the characters in the name).  The `-s` produces short output, but we already have `--porcelain=v1` output so is redundant (and probably should be removed).

If you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, the two characters are from each "side" of the merge, i.e., have more to do with the in-progress merge state than anything else.  In this case you can get `U` entries for either of the two characters.  That's not duplicable with `git diff-index`, and at least somewhat hard to do with `git diff-files`; it requires reading the higher-stage entries in the index, a la `git ls-files --stage`, or `git diff-files -1` and `git diff-files -2`.  (I have not experimented with `git diff-files -digit`.)

If we can ignore this unmerged-index case, though, the two characters are:

- On the left: `HEAD` vs index, one of A, D, M, or R; or blank, or a question mark, both of which occur only when forced by the character on the right.
- On the right: index vs work-tree, one of A, D, M, R, blank, or question-mark.

(The manual page lists `C`, copied, as a possible state.  This state *can* come out of Git's internal diff engine, but only if you enable copy-finding, and the `git status` command itself *does not* enable copy-finding by default and—at least at present—has no flags to direct it to so do, so the `C` state never actually occurs.)

The blank appears when the file is present in both of the two entities being compared, and is the same in both.  If file *F* appears in both `HEAD` (a commit) and the index, and is the same in both, its left-hand character state is blank, for instance.  However, if *F* then appears in both the index and work-tree and its state is the same in both, `git status` doesn't mention it at all, so you never get two blanks.  This is why I say that a blank occurs only when forced.

The question-mark state occurs when the file exists in the work-tree as an untracked file.  In this case the file is, by definition, *not* in the index: an untracked file is one that appears in the work-tree but not in the index.  So for this case, what you get is one line that reads `?? filename`.  Note that in *this* case, it's possible that the named file *does* appear in `HEAD`.  If that's true, it *must* be *deleted* in `HEAD`-vs-index.  One would think that this might appear as:

```
D? filename
```

which would make sense, but instead, Git shows this as:

```
D  filename
?? filename
```

i.e., the file appears twice, once for its HEAD-vs-index=deleted state (which shows no difference with the work-tree) and then again for its index-vs-work-tree=untracked state (which shows two question marks).

Now let's move on to the `grep`.  The `-E` argument supplies a regular expression that matches one of three alternatives, all of which are anchored to the beginning of the line, so we're always looking at the two `git status` characters.  The three expression alternatives are:

- `.M`: anything where the index-vs-work-tree state says *modified*.  The first dot accepts any HEAD-vs-index state.
- `[MA].`: anything where the HEAD-vs-index state says *modified* or *added*.  The second dot accepts any index-vs-work-tree state.
- `??`: untracked files.

> I think this could be achievable with e.g. `git-diff-index` ...

As [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index) says, this

> compare[s] a tree to the working tree or index

so, given `HEAD` as the tree on the left side of the comparison, and the specifier that says *use the working tree as the right side*, this runs the same comparison as the first half of `git status`.  So

```
git diff-index --cached HEAD [options]
```

does the same as the first half of `git status`, and can get you the equivalent of the letter codes you'd see on the left of `git status --short`.

To get the equivalent of the letter codes you'd see on the *right* half of `git status --short`, though, you must compare the index itself (not a tree) to the work-tree.  That's what [the `git diff-files` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-files) does.  So here you'll need:

```
git diff-files [options]
```

So, with some work, it *is* possible to get "the same" output.  We want:

1. The names of *M*-status files in the work-tree: `git diff-files --name-only --diff-filter=M`.
2. The names of *A* or *M* status files in the index: `git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=AM`.
3. Untracked files.  This cannot be done with either of the two `git diff-*` commands, but *can* be done with `git ls-files --other --exclude-standard` (you need the last option to make it respect the usual git-ignore rules).

Hence:

```
(
 git diff-files --name-only --diff-filter=M
 git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=AM
 git ls-files --other --exclude-standard
)
```

as a group of three commands should net you the same file names.  The main issue here is that if a file has *both* `A`-or-`M`-in-index *and* `M`-in-work-tree status, and you run these three commands in sequence like this, you'll see the file *twice*.  You can solve that by ending the command sequence with a pipe to `sort -u`:

```
(...) | sort -u
```

Note however that `git status --porcelain` *does* print the file name twice if it has both `D`-in-index and is untracked, so if you wanted to allow for `D`-in-index state, the `sort -u` result would not always match, because you'd now only see the file *once* instead.  (Then again, this is probably superior anyway.)